# Do we use "from" or "of" for cause of death?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

What is the difference in meaning when **of/from** are used:

1. He died **of** cancer

Compared to:

2. He died **from** electrocution

Both are correct sentences; are **of** and **from** interchangeable?

Comment: I have never come across either of your suggestions. The only expression I know is: **He was electrocuted** or, possibly, **He died after being electrocuted.**. However, Google Books Ngram Viewer shows that both constructions were in use until fairly recently: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=died+of+electrocution%2Cdied+from+electrocution&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=15&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdied%20of%20electrocution%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdied%20from%20electrocution%3B%2Cc0

Comment: So this is just a rot learning where with disease use of and with others i don't know use from

Comment: I would have no issue with either preposition being used in either context.

Comment: Yes it only a concern for student who is giving the exam. Teachers can explain based on answers they see

Comment: If you fell off a cliff, then you died from falling off a cliff (it is not a disease).

Answer (score 1):

*Of X* leans towards associating the death with A) something that was going on for a long time or B) a category of some sort, whereas *from X* leans towards saying X was the direct cause of death and didn't necessarily last for months or years.

For example, if you say *He died *of* electrocution*, it sounds like you're keeping track of causes of deaths for a number of people, or filling out a form where that is done, but *He died from electrocution* seems like it's directly intended to answer the question "How did he die?".

Comment: Yup i was thinking of this logic between cancer/electrocution while eating. With ur confirmation i will stick to it. Thanks for ur response sir.

Comment: My book says "of" is preposition for cause while "from" for purpose. But both seems same to me and in some questions i get stuck.What's the difference??

Comment: There's a lot of overlap between certain pairs of English prepositions, and sometimes the reason why a specific preposition is used in various places is idiomatic - e.g. there's no real reason.  Or multiple prepositions could be used with only small differences in meaning that usually don't matter.  It's just the nature of language.